# The issue is occurred when deploying the Nginx docker image on the GKE cluster of the GCP using terraform

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am going to deploy Nginx docker image on the Google kubernetes cluster of the GCP using terraform. terraform init and terraform plan was done and cluster creation complete massaged appeared on the terminal. But deploymen has not been done and popped up some error.

This is the main.tf code

```
variable "project_id" {
  description = "The ID of the GCP project"
  default = "ben-project"
}

variable "cluster_name" {
  description = "The name of the GKE cluster"
  default = "nginx-cluster"
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = file("ben-project-6a028256d353.json")
  project = var.project_id
  region  = "us-central1"
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "nginx" {
  name = var.cluster_name
  location = "us-central1-a"
  initial_node_count = 1

  node_config {
    machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "nginx" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx-deployment"
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "nginx"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "nginx"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = "nginx:latest"
          name  = "nginx"
          port {
            container_port = 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "nginx" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx-service"
  }

  spec {
    selector = {
      app = "nginx"
    }

    port {
      name       = "http"
      port       = 80
      target_port = 80
    }

    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}

output "kubernetes_api_endpoint" {
  value = google_container_cluster.nginx.endpoint
}

output "nginx_external_ip" {
    value = kubernetes_service.nginx.status[0].load_balancer[0].ingress[0].ip
}
```

Please you can find the error massage here,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxfTb.png)

I tried different solutions but it couldn't solve yet.

I have tried most of the ways to solve that. But it was useless.
I wanted to deploy Nginx docker image on GKE using terraform successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You missing the connection to the **GKE cluster**, once your cluster is **Ready** K8s client needs details to connect to the GKE cluster.

You have successfully created the but **K8s** client don't have idea so by default it's connecting on **localhost:8080** as shown in image error.

You can use the

```
data "google_client_config" "provider" {}

data "google_container_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name     = var.cluster_name
  location = "us-central1"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host  = "https://${data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.endpoint}"
  token = data.google_client_config.provider.access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(
    data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.master_auth[0].cluster_ca_certificate,
  )
}
```

after this your code will be able to deploy the POD or K8s resource on GKE cluster. You can also use the service account for auth as per need.

Read more & example at : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/using_gke_with_terraform

Also refer the document of K8s client you are using : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/deployment